# Generate automatic movement

Tags: java

I am trying to generate an automatic movement for a soccer player. Trying to create the 8 possible cases that the player has, but when I am going to execute them, the player does not move, I do not know if I am calling the movement wrong or returning the movement wrong. Here is an image of how the court is:[image]

```
package players;
public class SuJugador implements Player 
{
     public int[] move(int[][] history, int player) 
{
        int []  Move= new int [2];
        int x=history[history.length-1][0];
        int y=history[history.length-1][1];
            /*.
             * |---|---|---|
             * | 1 | 2 | 3 | 
             * |---|---|---|
             * |           |
             * |     4     |
             * |           |
             * |___________|
             * | 5 | 6 | 7 |
             * |---|---|---|
             */
        if (player == 0)
        {
            // CUANDO LLEGUE A LA CACHA DE ARRIBA
            if((x==4)&&(y==2))
            {
                Move=casos(1, history);
                if((validMove(Move,history)==true)&& 
  (limit(Move[0],Move[1])==true))
                {
                  return Move;
                }
            }
            if((x==5)&&(y==2))
            {
                Move=casos(2, history);
                if((validMove(Move,history)==true)&& 
  (limit(Move[0],Move[1])==true))
                {
                  return Move;
                }
            }
            if((x==6)&&(y==2))
            {
                Move=casos(3, history);
                if((validMove(Move,history)==true)&& 
   (limit(Move[0],Move[1])==true))
                {
                  return Move;
                }
            }
            //Medio Total
            if((x==5)&&(y==7))
            {
                Move=casos(1, history);
                if((validMove(Move,history)==true)&& 
   (limit(Move[0],Move[1])==true))
                {
                  return Move;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
public static int[] casos(int $id,int[][]history) 
{
    {
        int []  Move= new int [2];
        int x=history[history.length-1][0];
        int y=history[history.length-1][1];
        switch ($id)
    {
    case 1: x=history[history.length-1][0];
            y=history[history.length-1][1];                        
            Move[0]=x;
            Move[1]=y-1; 
            break;

    case 2: x=history[history.length-1][0];
            y=history[history.length-1][1];                        
            Move[0]=x+1;
            Move[1]=y-1; 
            break;

    case 3: x=history[history.length-1][0];
            y=history[history.length-1][1];                        
            Move[0]=x-1;
            Move[1]=y-1; 
            break;

    case 4: x=history[history.length-1][0];
            y=history[history.length-1][1];                        
            Move[0]=x;
            Move[1]=y+1; 
            break;


    case 5: x=history[history.length-1][0];
            y=history[history.length-1][1];                        
            Move[0]=x+1;
            Move[1]=y; 
            break;

    case 6: x=history[history.length-1][0];
            y=history[history.length-1][1];                        
            Move[0]=x-1;
            Move[1]=y; 
            break;

    case 7: x=history[history.length-1][0];
            y=history[history.length-1][1];                        
            Move[0]=x+1;
            Move[1]=y+1; 
            break;

    case 8: x=history[history.length-1][0];
            y=history[history.length-1][1];                        
            Move[0]=x-1;
            Move[1]=y+1; 
            break;

    }
    }
return null;
}
public static boolean limit (int x, int y) 
{
       if ((x>=1)&&(x<=9)&&(y>=2)&&(y<=12)) 
       {
           return true;
       }           
       if (((y==1)||(y==13))&&(x==4)||(x==5)||(x==6))
       {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
}
public static boolean validMove(int []FutMov,int[][]history) 
{       
     if (history.length>1)
     {          
        boolean permitex=false;
        boolean permitey=false;
        int Posx=history[history.length-1][0];
        int Posy=history[history.length-1][1];

        for (int i=0;i<history.length-1;i++)
        {

            if (history[i][0]== Posx)
            {
                if (history[i+1][0]== FutMov[0]) 
                {
                    permitex =false;
                }
                else 
                {
                    permitex= true;
                }
            }
            if (history[i][1]==Posy)
            {
                if (history[i+1][1]== FutMov[1]) 
                {
                    permitey=false;
                }
                else 
                {
                    permitey= true;
                }
            }
        }
        return (permitey||permitex);    
     } 
     return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I do not know if I am calling the movement wrong or returning the movement wrong.

Apparently, you forgot to return the move from your `casos()` function, which only does `return null;`.